# How to disable optimizations in the as assembler?

Tags: optimization, assembly

I would like to find a way to assemble assembly code into the opcodes I want, not what the assemblerwants! (Something like gcc -O0 but for assembly). My reasons involve teaching etc, etc.

For example AS likes to change MOV r1, r2 into ADD r1, r2, #0.

This is all very well when I'm looking for faster code but not so great for teaching when I need the correct opcodes.
I'm using AS and LD in a linux environment (ARM processor). Any ideas?

Comment: I am not aware of such an option, and my `as` (version 2.22.51.20120116) does not change this `mov` into an `add`.

Comment: No, this rings a bell. I might put an answer in for this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some syntax changes from earlier ARM assembly language to preferred syntax. For example: STMFD sp!, reglist became PUSH reglist.

Here's a reference I found that mentions this: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cjagjjbc.html

It also states that, in reference to Thumb instructions:

"If Rd and Rn are both Lo registers, MOV Rd, Rn is disassembled as ADDS Rd, Rn, #0."

which may be what you are seeing.

Comment: This led me to what I think might be the right answer. I am using thumb mode and when I check the HI registers I was getting the correct opcodes. Question, why does this happen even though thumb contains instructions for mov lo reg reg?

Comment: I'm not sure - I suppose the opcodes are the same binary values. In Intel X86 a NOP will disassemble as "XOR EAX, EAX" which seems bizarre but as the effect is precisely the same the opcode values are too!